# Unable to get Python "ibm_db" module using pip install

Tags: python, pip, db2, python-module

I am trying to install `ibm_db` module for python using pip install but getting below error.

> " C:\Users\n087514>pip install ibm_db Collecting ibm-db   Using cached
>   https://repo-man.aetna.com/nexus/repository/ae-pypi-group/packages/f8/6f/5f8186cb31021409235a948be5e29d77761ef92747a101360003747c4105/ibm_db-2.0.8.tar.gz
>   Installing collected packages: ibm-db   Running setup.py install for
>   ibm-db ... error
>       Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_w1_snzp\ibm-db\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-g_xrj1vq-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_w1_snzp\ibm-db\setup.py",
>   line 17, in 
>           os.rename('tests','test_2')
>       FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'tests' -> 'test_2'
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python 3.5\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_w1_snzp\ibm-db\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-g_xrj1vq-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\n087514\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_w1_snzp\ibm-db\"

Anyone has any idea what needs to be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`pip install "ibm_db==2.0.8a"`